# how to rearrange my textview in my relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Here's my layout screenshot:

[image]

How can I arrange all these **TextView** for them to have a good format (heading being Taking responsibility (means being aware)..) alignment etc.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Menu"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    >


    <TextView
        android:text="*Follow safety guide for moving around the town and between towns."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />

    <TextView
    android:text="*Avoid crowds and do not participate actively in demonstrations even when it is related to programme work."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:gravity="left"


        android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="*Avoid crowds and do not participate actively in demonstrations even when it is related to programme work."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView25" />

    <TextView
    android:text="*keep this briefing pack in an accessible place, and the    emergency numbers in your mobile phone memory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView28"

        android:layout_above="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Taking resposibility(means being aware)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="*Avoid moving around town by yourself and always make others aware of your location."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"

        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="*Share any security information that might have implications for Ballloon Ventures to the Country Manager or pc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="*If using host home accommondation,check that it is secure.if it is not,tell the Programme Coordinator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView28"

        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView25" />

    <TextView
        android:text="*Report all incidents to your Programmer Cordinator."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Because if I drag one TextView it affecting all other TextView.

Comment: Define "good format".  If you ask a specific thing to do we might help you, but good format depends on the user.  I suggest you look at RelativeLayout and what the android:layout_xxx properties mean, and draw out how you want it to look on paper (or in paint, photoshop, etc).  Then edit those properties to make it look that way.

Comment: can you show how you wanted to design?

Comment: i have update the image of how the activity.If u look at it all my Textview are not organised how can i rearrange them for the display please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GabeSechan said, you need to learn what **android:layout_xxx** properties in **RelativeLayout** means.

When you moving a View in RelativeLayout via Layout Editor, you need to consider some of the following properties in your layout:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/textView25"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView25"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

- `android:layout_above="@+id/textView25"` means that you want the View above **textView25** view.
- `android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"` means that you want the View below **textView25** View.
- The following properties means that you want the view to the right side of **TextView25** View:

  ```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView25"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView25"
  ```
- The following properties means that you want the view to align with the left side of the parent layout:

  ```
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  ```

If you want to edit views position in a RelativeLayout, please ***don't depends*** with drag and drop via Layout Editor. You better do it manually except you want to have a headache later. Use Layout Editor to view the design result.

Design with a paper or imagination first, then code it after that.

Try to learn it from:

- [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)
- [Constructing View Layouts](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Constructing-View-Layouts)

Comment: i have update the image of how the activity.If u look at it all my Textview are not organised how can i rearrange them for the display please

Comment: From your image, you want to make text after the title align vertical, right? You can do it by adding `android:layout_below="@+id/your_first_text_not_title"` to the second text, then in the third text, you can add `android:layout_below="@+id/your_second_text"`. Make a copy of layout before editing, and clean your layout from unused properties.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for doing that would be to open a splitview between your code and design views and then editing the code to place the text in the correct location, using attributes such as padding, margin, aligning, below, above, etc. refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm) guide for positioning stuff in relative layout and combine it with other formatting attributes such as margin and padding.

Comment: i have update the image of how the activity.If u look at it all my Textview are not organised how can i rearrange them for the display please